# How do i show that $w=z^2$ maps $|z-1|\leq 1$ onto $R=2(1+\cos \theta)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do i show that $w=z^2$ maps $|z-1|\leq 1$ onto the cardioid $R=2(1+\cos \theta)$?

Comment: That should be $\lvert z-1\rvert = 1$, not $\le 1$. Write $z = 1+e^{i\varphi} = (e^{-i\varphi/2}+ e^{i\varphi/2})e^{i\varphi/2} = \left(2\cos \frac{\varphi}{2}\right)e^{i\varphi/2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mr. Fischer has given a very effective hint in his comment. The following approach will give the same result.

$z = x + iy$. So the circle $|z - 1| = 1$ can be written as $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ or by $x = 1 + \cos(\theta), y = \sin(\theta)$.

$z^2 = x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy$. Write $u = x^2 - y^2$ and $v = 2ixy$. Represent $u$ and $v$ by function of $\theta$. $u = 1 + 2\cos(\theta) + \cos(2 \theta)$ and $v = 2\sin(\theta) + \sin(2\theta)$ in simplified form.

$r^2 = u^2 + v^2$ and simplifying get $r^2 = 4(1 + cos(\theta))^2$ and so $r$.

Now see the fact that the function $z^2$ is entire and so conformal. Hence answer.